# 1140 grid ipad portrait

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm attempting to use the 1140 grid from cssgrid.net and am running into an issue. On screens between 768px - 795px, the right padding on the .container div is not working. Instead, the content begins to butt up against the right edge of the browser window. I'm viewing my site in the newest version of Chrome on Mac (and the main issue with this range is that iPads in portrait are 768px).

The same thing seems to be happening on [cssgrid.net](http://cssgrid.net) with the "download" button at top right.

I've come up with a temporary work around on [a site I'm working on](http://future.thefutureforward.com/~conant/sliced/), that changes the padding on screens of this size to 5px instead of 20 within 1140.css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 795px){ 
.container{ padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; } 
}
```

but this seems like an unnecessary work around (and I would much rather have the 20px of padding, as 5 is a bit close for comfort).

If you have any insight into this, it would be so appreciated.

Comment: Just for testing, can you change the viewport meta tag to <meta name="viewport" content="width=1140px" />

Comment: That fixed the padding issue, though now it is pretty zoomed out and looking quite odd.

Comment: When I resize the desktop version of Chrome to 768px wide (ie, same width as iPad in portrait orientation), I'm seeing issues as well.  It doesn't seem like this is unique to the iPad.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. The issue is happening for screen sizes between 768px and roughly 795px, so I changed my "hack" media query in 1040.css to: @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 795px){ .container{ padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; } }

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly fix, but you might be able to use php to check if the user is on an iPad, then change the `viewport` to be 1024px wide. Replace your current viewport meta tag with something like this:

```
<?
    $is_ipad = false;
    // check if user agent is an iPad
    if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad') ){
        $is_ipad = true;
    }

    // if it's an ipad, set viewport to 1024px wide
    if ($is_ipad){
        echo '<meta name = "viewport" content="width=1024">';
    }

    // if not an ipad, use device width
    else {
        echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Yea, that could work...but since the issue isn't restricted to iPads but instead all devices at that screen size, I'm hoping for a better solution. Thanks for the idea, though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in min-width. Add this to grid styles

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .row {
        min-width: 720px;
    }
}
```